# Cant Change DropDown text while processing another DropDown

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I have 2 DropDowns on an excel sheet which work independently of each other. The selections on both drop down's can cause confusion during reporting generation. So I need to set DropDown#1 to "select"  if DropDown2 is being used by the user and vice versa. 
I am trying to use the DropDown.Text property but it does not do the trick.

```
Sub PDropDown_Click()

Dim DropDownP As DropDown
Dim DropDownD As DropDown
Set DropDownD = Me.DropDowns("DDropDown")
Set DropDownP = Me.DropDowns("PDropDown")
DropDownD.Text ="Select"
DropDownP.Text = DropDownP.List(DropDownP.ListIndex)
Call Report_Generator.Create_Graph(DropDownP.List(DropDownP.ListIndex))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the value select to you combo boxes.

```
Dim bExit as Boolean

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If bExit = True Then
        bExit = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    bExit = True
    ComboBox2.Text = "Select"

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    If bExit = True Then
        bExit = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    bExit = True
    ComboBox1.Text = "Select"
End Sub
```